# unable to find http Karaf feature

Tags: osgi, cxf, apache-karaf

On Karaf 3.0.4, I try to use CXF.

```
karaf@root()> feature:repo-add mvn:org.apache.cxf.karaf/apache-cxf/3.0.4/xml/features
Adding feature url mvn:org.apache.cxf.karaf/apache-cxf/3.0.4/xml/features
karaf@root()> feature:install cxf
Error executing command: Can't install feature cxf/0.0.0:   
No feature named 'http' with version '0.0.0' available
```

Where is the 'http' feature supposed to come from? I can't find the right feature repository.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out someone changed the featuresRepositories in our Karaf's etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg to use the 4.0.4 instead of 3.0.4 of the standard features.  Duh!